# Draw an array to the position of a Draggable in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an array of draggable container in a Stack and I want to create arrows form one to another.
The best way I have found is to put a CustomPainter on the background of my Stack and to draw the array each time the position of a view change (for now it's just a line to see if everything is running smoothly).
This work well when my container isn't moving (line on the left):
[image: Container with his arrow on left]

Now my problem is when drag my object, a desynchronization between the position of the container and the line appear (lag?).
[Here's a video of the problem](https://youtu.be/YowDgjlMNj4)

- How can I fix this problem?
- Is there a better way to make these arrows

Here is my code:
ExampleContainer (build the stack with all ExampleView inside)

```
class ExampleContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ExampleContainerState createState() => ExampleContainerState();
}

class ExampleContainerState extends State<ExampleContainer> {
  Map viewsInfo = {};
  bool firstInit = true;

  ExampleContainerState() {
    this.viewsInfo['1'] = {'position': Offset(100, 100), 'leftArrow': Offset(0, 0)};
  }


  positionDidMove(String id, Offset offset) {
    this.setState((){
      this.viewsInfo[id]['position'] = offset;
    });
  }

  positionMoving(String id, Offset left) {
    this.setState(() {
      this.viewsInfo[id]['leftArrow'] = left;
    });
  }

  getArrows(String id, ExampleView tmp) {
    Offset left = tmp.getArrowPosition();

    this.viewsInfo[id]['leftArrow'] = left;
  }

  List<Widget> allViews() {
    List<Widget> toRet = new List<Widget>();
    this.viewsInfo.forEach((k, v) {
      ExampleView tmp = ExampleView(parent: this, id: k, width: 300, height: 500, x: v['position'].dx, y: v['position'].dy);
      if (this.firstInit)
        this.getArrows(k, tmp);
      toRet.add(tmp);
    });
    this.firstInit = false;
    toRet.insert(0, CustomPaint(
      painter: ArrowPainter(viewsInfo: this.viewsInfo),
      size: Size.infinite,
    ));
    return toRet;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: this.allViews(),
    );
  }

}
```

ArrowPainter (Draw the lines)

```
class ArrowPainter extends CustomPainter {
  ArrowPainter({this.viewsInfo});

  final Map viewsInfo;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    viewsInfo.forEach((k, v) {
      final p1 = Offset(v['leftArrow'].dx, v['leftArrow'].dy);
      final p2 = Offset(v['leftArrow'].dx - 20, v['leftArrow'].dy);
      final paint = Paint()
        ..color = Colors.black
        ..strokeWidth = 4;
      canvas.drawLine(p1, p2, paint);
    });
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(ArrowPainter old) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

ExampleView (the draggable view container). The best way I found to get current position of the container is to use a Listener but it seems odd to me that I don't have another way.

```
class ExampleView extends StatefulWidget {
  ExampleView({Key key, this.parent, this.id, this.width, this.height, this.x = 0, this.y = 0}): super(key: key);

  final double width;
  final double height;
  final double x;
  final double y;
  final String id;
  final ExampleContainerState parent;

  @override
  _ExampleView createState() => _ExampleView();

  Offset getArrowPosition() {
    return Offset(x, y + (height / 2));
  }
}

class _ExampleView extends State<ExampleView> {
  final GlobalKey _feedbackKey = GlobalKey();


  void endMove(Offset offset) {
    widget.parent.positionDidMove(widget.id, offset);
  }

  void move(Offset offset) {
    Offset left = Offset(offset.dx, offset.dy + (widget.height / 2));
    widget.parent.positionMoving(widget.id, left);
  }

  Container getContainer() {
    return Container(
      child: Center(child: Text('Container'),),
      width: widget.width,
      height: widget.height,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(width: 1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
        top: widget.y,
        left: widget.x,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Listener(
                onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent event) {
                  if (this._feedbackKey.currentContext == null)
                    return;
                  RenderBox tmp = this._feedbackKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
                  this.move(tmp.localToGlobal(Offset.zero));
                },
                child: Draggable(
                  child: this.getContainer(),
                  feedback: Container(child: this.getContainer(), key: this._feedbackKey),
                  childWhenDragging: Container(),
                  onDraggableCanceled: (Velocity velocity, Offset offset){
                    this.endMove(offset);
                  },
                )
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }

}
```

Thanks to everyone who took the time to read my problem. This is one of my first tests in Flutter and I'm open to any comments to improve my code.

Edit : I added a video of the problem

Comment: If possible can you share complete screen shot with multiple containers and all arrows.

Comment: @CrazyLazyCat I just added a video of the problem where you can see multiple containers. As I said, for now it's just a line on the left of each container to see if everything is running smoothly.